# Autoreconf failing when installing (py)COMPSs in a clusters

Tags: java, python, distributed-computing, compss, pycompss

I tried to install pyCOMPSs (v1.4) on a Cluster system using the
installation script for Supercomputers.
The script terminates with the following error:

```
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libcbindings.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libcbindings.la" && ln -s
"../libcbindings.la" "libcbindings.la" )
make[1]: Entering directory
`/home/xxx/repos/pycompss/COMPSs/Bindings/c/src/bindinglib'
  /usr/bin/mkdir -p
'/home/cramonco/svn/compss/framework/trunk/builders/specs/deb/compss-c-binding/tmp/opt/COMPSs/Bindings/c/lib'
/usr/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/cramonco’: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory
`/home/xxx/xxx/repos/pycompss/COMPSs/Bindings/c/src/bindinglib'
make: *** [install-am] Error 2

BindingLib Installation failed, please check errors above!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems the error is due to the package includes a previous configuration
and in your case the autoreconf is not overwritting the Makefile and
other files produced by autotools.  try with
running

```
cd /home/xxx/repos/pycompss/COMPSs/Bindings/c/src/bindinglib
make maintainer-clean
```

After this run again the install command